# Create instance of a subclass based on a parent instance?

Tags: c#, class, properties, subclass

Consider the following class definitions:

```
class A
{
    public int Property1 { get; set; }
    public int Property2 { get; set; }
}

class B : A // note that B is a subclass of A
{
    // B has only one further property
    public int OneMoreProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Given an instance of `A`, I need to create an instance of `B` with the same values. Is there any better way to do this than copying over each property? Any chance to use the fact that `B` is a subclass of `A` ? This is what I currently have and what's very inconvenient and error prone in my opinion:

```
// Create instance of A
A instanceA = new A();
instanceA.Property1 = 1;
instanceA.Property2 = 2;

// Create instance of B with same 
// values as the instance of A
B instanceB = new B();
instanceB.Property1 = instanceA.Property1;
instanceB.Property2 = instanceA.Property2;
instanceB.OneMoreProperty = 5;
```

Comment: First things first - are you sure inheritance is the best tool for the job here? Is B _really_ an A (ie B `is-a` A) ? Or more accurately should there be an `has-a` relationship (ie B should have an instance of A)

Answer (score 3):

As @Jamiec mentions, the inheritance relationship here may be better modelled through composition, but if `B` semantically is an `A`, one way would be to add a "copy constructor":

```
class A
{
    public int Property1 { get; set; }
    public int Property2 { get; set; }

    public A() { }
    public A(A other)
    {
        Property1 = other.Property1;
        Property2 = other.Property2;
    }
}

class B : A
{
    public int OneMoreProperty { get; set; }

    public B() { }
    public B(A other) : base(other) { }
}
```

Then when you create your `B` instance:

```
B instanceB = new B(instanceA);
instanceB.OneMoreProperty = 5;
```

Comment: Thanks for writing the "copy constructor" answer, it is of course the right way if there really is a need for inheritance, I've written the _other_ answer.

Answer (score 2):

You've given a very clear illustration of why inheritance for the purpose of "reusing" properties is very often the wrong choice.

Inheritance implies an `is-a` relationship, but what you've modelled here is almost certainly an `has-a` relationship between A & B. Therefore `B` should just hold an instance of A, negating the need to "copy the values" from A to B.

```
class A
{
    public int Property1 { get; set; }
    public int Property2 { get; set; }
}

class B 
{
    public A A{ get; set; }
    public int OneMoreProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Then

```
// Create instance of A
A instanceA = new A();
instanceA.Property1 = 1;
instanceA.Property2 = 2;

// Create instance of B with same 
// values as the instance of A
B instanceB = new B();
instanceB.A = instanceA;
instanceB.OneMoreProperty = 5;
```

This is an obvious over simplification, you may well instead have a constructor which takes `A`, and you may introduce interfaces in so that you can make both `A` and `B` behave in some shared way that makes sense to your domain.

You should also consider Immutability of your objects, as changes to an instance of `A` in the above example will impact the reference held by `B`.

Comment: I would consider mentioning immutability, since this helps ensures that changing a property on one object does not unintentionally affect another object.

Answer (score 0):

I know what exactly you mean, Sometimes there are classes that we cannot cast because of that one more property. This can be acheived using Reflection:

```
static Tout CopyProps<Tin, Tout>(Tin input) where Tout: Tin, new()
{
     var result = new Tout();
     foreach (var prop in typeof(Tin).GetProperties())
         prop.SetValue(result, prop.GetValue(input));
     return result;
}
```

The usage would be:

```
var a = new A{...}
var b = CopyProps<A,B>(a);
```